# filter all details of id if matched with criteria in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe:

```r
d = data.frame(
  'Id'=c(101,101,102,102,103,103,104,104,105,105),
  'Description'=c('Date Change','Not P','Data Change','Not P','Date Change','Absent','Date Updated','Not P','finalupdate','Present'),
  'Time'=c(23,23,42,54,56,12,98,32,54,65))
```

I want to filter out all details of Id which has Description 'Not P, like id 101 has Description "Not P" same with Id 102, so I want all details of these Id.

I thought of doing with loop but i think there might be some easy way of doing it in R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `filter` after doing a `group_by`

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% 
   group_by(Id) %>% 
   filter(! 'Not P' %in% Description) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#     Id Description  Time
#  <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
#1   103 Date Change    56
#2   103 Absent         12
#3   105 finalupdate    54
#4   105 Present        65
```

To do the reverse, remove the negate (`!`)

```
d %>%
    group_by(Id) %>%
    filter('Not P' %in% Description) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#    Id Description   Time
#  <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>
#1   101 Date Change     23
#2   101 Not P           23
#3   102 Data Change     42
#4   102 Not P           54
#5   104 Date Updated    98
#6   104 Not P           32
```

---

Or using `base R` with `subset`

```
subset(d, !Id %in% Id[Description == 'Not P'])
subset(d, Id %in% Id[Description == 'Not P'])
```